# Are 行きゃあ and 行きゃ both contractions of 行けば?

Tags: contractions, spoken-language

I started playing another old game, [Game Boy Wars Advance 2](http://www.nintendo.co.jp/n08/bgwj/), and I ran across this bit of dialogue:

> ま、どのみち、マクロランドに**行きゃあ**、
>   いやでも戦わなきゃなんねえんだ。

I think this is something like:

> ま、どのみち、マクロランドに**行けば**、
>   いやでも戦わなければならないのだ。

Thanks to [a helpful comment by Tsuyoshi Ito](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/511?m=7952002#7952002), I learned that `おけば` can be contracted to `おきゃ`.  More generally, I learned that `e + ば` can be contracted to `ゃ` (small や).  Based on this rule, I'm guessing that `行きゃ` is a contraction of `行けば`.

Of course, the dialogue I quoted says `行きゃあ`, not `行きゃ`.  My guess is that `e + ば` can *also* be contracted to `ゃあ`, and based on this I guess that both `行きゃあ` and `行きゃ` are contracted forms of `行けば`.  Is this correct?

(My other guess is that perhaps it's `行ければ`...?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra あ only comes from lengthening the きゃ and could equally well have been written 行きゃ～. Just in the middle of the sentence it looks better as 行きゃあ.

The sound is lengthened, because there is a small break when saying the sentence. For example, in

> 行きゃいいじゃねぇか
>   Why don't you go?

a lengthening wouldn't be natural.

I presume if you really want, 行ければ can also be contracted to 行きゃ, but 行けりゃ probably works better.

Comment: Do you think the same thing about [ちゃ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=112609200000) and [ちゃあ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%82&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss)?  In that case, I thought the あ was the uncontracted /a/ from は, but I just realized the dictionary doesn't say which it is.

Comment: Oh, definitely. Whether you want ちゃ or ちゃあ only depends on the position in the sentence, not so much on the meaning. In both cases ては becomes ちゃ and あ is only added for lengthening, if natural in the flow of the sentence.

Comment: I found a post by Bart Mathias about `ちゃあ` and `ちゃ` http://groups.google.com/group/sci.lang.japan/msg/a276c9c0c4e5a8e1